# Graph-tool: How to access properties of a copied graph

Tags: python, python-2.7, graph, graph-tool

I created a filtered graph of the graph g and would like to use it as a new graph. As far as I know the properties are also copied, but how can I access them? If I use "weight" it would be the property map of g not sub.

```
weight = g.new_edge_property('float')
vfilt = g.new_vertex_property('bool')
...
old_sub = gt.GraphView(g, vfilt)
sub = gt.Graph(old_sub, directed=False, prune=True)
```

If the properties are not copied to sub, how can a do that. Since the new graph has not the same number of vertices, the index of the vertices has changed.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the properties "internal" to the graph before copying:

```
weight = g.new_edge_property('float')
vfilt = g.new_vertex_property('bool')
...
old_sub = gt.GraphView(g, vfilt)
old_sub.ep.weight = weight   # old_sub.ep is a dictionary of internal properties
sub = gt.Graph(old_sub, directed=False, prune=True)
sub_weight = sub.ep.weight   # copy of weight
```